# Implementing two way data-binding WebView using MVVM in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, webview

I am trying to implement MVVM in all my app and I am very new to this, so I want to load a webview through my ViewModel, but I don't know the best way how to do this, if also has a progress bar that shows up when my web view is loading.

Here's the code:

```
    class NewWebViewFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: NewWebViewViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val binding: FragmentWebViewBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_web_view, container, false)

        val webViewModelo = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NewWebViewViewModel::class.java)

        binding.webViewModel = webViewModelo
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this


        return binding.root
    }

}
```

Now my ViewModel:

```
class NewWebViewViewModel : ViewModel() {

//Implement in MVVM

private fun showWebView(webView: WebView, progressBar: ProgressBar) {

        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()

        val webSettings = webView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        webView.loadUrl("https://brand.randombrand.com/en/")

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my XML:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <data>
        <variable
            name="webViewModel"
            type="com.example.navigations.viewmodel.webview.NewWebViewViewModel" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".fragments.WebViewFragment">


    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    </WebView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>


    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

The Error I get is a `nullpointerexception` cause the webview i'm passing is null.
Any thoughts of the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best option for you would be to create a Binding Adapter that will look like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("loadUrl")
fun WebView.setUrl(url: String) {
    this.loadUrl(url)
}
```

In your ViewModel you can either receive the data through Fragment arguments (maybe if they come from another Fragment) or just have them modified from the ViewModel.

In the VM the data will be the url to be loaded, maybe like `val webViewUrl = MutableLiveData<String>().apply{ value = "initial url to be loaded .com" }`.

And in your xml:

```
<WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        app:loadUrl="@{viewModel.webViewUrl}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

And yes, you should never do UI stuff in the ViewModel, like instantiating a WebView, or something like that.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment! Where should I implement these bindingAdapters? do they belong in the View Fragment?

Comment: You can create like a Utils class that has only Binding Adapters, that's usually how I do it :)

Answer (score 2):

you might not use `webview` in `viewmodel`

look https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters.html

Rules of MVVM

**Rule Number One**: View should not have any logic in it, not at all! Not even a simple if condition. All logic for the view happens in ViewModel.

**Rule Number Two**: In response to events view does nothing except notifying view-model by calling a method. View does not pass any view related classes to view model.

**Rule Number Three**: ViewModel uses live data as the main way to communicate to view!

One of the benefits of MVVM is that ViewModel doesn’t have to know anything about the View and has no reference to View classes! Instead, it uses the reactive programming paradigm, so View can still observer the data and be notified about the changes.

**Rule Number Four**: View can call view-model whenever it needs something. ViewModel can provide helper methods for the view.

Comment: This was a very very nice comment :) Thank you for the insight and good practices

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to load the webView. Here's what I've done:

```
 import android.webkit.WebView
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter

object Utilities {

    @BindingAdapter("loadUrl")
    @JvmStatic
    fun WebView.setUrl(url: String) {
        this.loadUrl(url)
    }
}
```

1# created an object for Utils

```
<WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
            app:loadUrl="@{webViewModel.webViewUrl}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            >
```

2 # Updated XML to Look like this

3 # val webViewUrl = MutableLiveData().apply{ value = "https://google.com/en/" }

added this to my ViewModel Class

Thanks for the comments guys